# Check if Python wheel exists on PyPI before installing build dependencies

Tags: python, pip, pypi, python-packaging, python-wheel

I have a CI job that builds my project for many architectures. In this process I install `pygit2` with `pip` which depends on `libgit2`. In some cases pip installs the wheel from PyPI and no other build dependencies are required. But, for some architectures no wheel exists so pygit2's setup script is executed, which requires libgit2's sources on the system. In this case I have to compile libgit2 from source. As this is a resource intensive process, I would like to perform it only for the cases where no wheel exists for the specific architecture.

How do I check (maybe with pip) if a wheel exists for the currently used system/architecture exists on PyPI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into the following `pip install` and/or `pip download` options:

- [*`--only-binary <format_control>`*](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-only-binary)
- [*`--prefer-binary`*](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-prefer-binary)

Maybe something like the following could come close enough to a reliable way to check if a wheel is available or not (either check the exit code or check if a wheel has actually been downloaded):

```
pip download --no-deps --only-binary :all: pygit2
```

Comment: Is there a way to not perform the install, but only check it at first?

Comment: You could try the same options with `pip download`. Otherwise you will probably need another tool. And then you can always query _PyPI_'s API directly.

Comment: But I am confused... do you want to install or only check? Your question seems to indicate that you want to install while avoiding source distributions and that's exactly what those options do, don't they?

Comment: I could install it first but my original intention was: 1. only check if wheel exists for pygit2, 2. if no wheel install libgit2 from source, 3. install all dependencies from requirements.txt. If I would use pip install --only-binary … i would end up with 1. try to install pygit2, 2. install libgit2 if 1 fails, 3. install all dependencies from requirements.txt, which would do the job but is in my eyes less elegant.

Comment: Have you tried something like `pip download --no-deps --only-binary :all: pygit2` and then either check the return code or check if something was actually downloaded. If this does not work then I have no other idea than going to the PyPI API or scraping the PyPI website. -- Or you would need to maintain a list in your CI settings of the environments that require a installation of libgit2.